# f.write fails to record inputs

Tags: python

Suppose such a **text**

```
In [134]: !cat test1.md                                                                                           
The first test
```

I open it and write contents

```
In [156]: f1 = open("test1.md", "r+")                                                                             

In [157]: f1.write("The second test")                                                                             
Out[157]: 15

In [158]: !cat test1.md                                                                                           
The first test
test second method
```

It works correctly until now, if continue to `input`

```
In [159]: f1.write("The third test")                                                                              
Out[159]: 14

In [160]: !cat test1.md                                                                                           
The first test
test second method


In [161]: f1.write("The fourth  test")                                                                            
Out[161]: 16

In [162]: !cat test1.md                                                                                           
The first test
test second method
```

What's the problem with `f.write`?.

Comment: try f.flush() ?

Comment: Where did "test second method" come from?

Comment: Try `f.close()`?

Comment: Check out this, might help https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/file_flush.htm

Comment: thanks for your kindness @AbhijithShivaswamy

Answer (score 0):

You need to `flush()` the buffer then `close()` the file. Also maybe append your strings to the file.

```
f1 = open("test1.md", "a") # "a" means append to file                                                                          

f1.write("The second test")
f1.flush()
f1.close()
```

The`cat` the file;

```
cat test1.md                                                                                           

The first test
test second method
```

---

## The Correcct way.

You should really be doing it like this;

```
with open("test1.md", "a") as f1:
    f1.write("The second test")
    f1.flush()
    f1.close()
```